# Creating web applications with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to create a database web application using eclipse. I am using tomcat and derby.

I followed the instructions on link
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-EclipseDbWebapps/

but seem to be getting the folloing error

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable  
to get connection, DataSource invalid: "org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' for connect URL 
'jdbc:derby:D:\MyDB'"
```

can anyone help out

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:derby:D:/MyDB'"
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:derby:D:/MyDB'"
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.demo_jsp._jspService(demo_jsp.java:124)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:derby:D:/MyDB'"
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.getConnection(QueryTagSupport.java:276)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.doStartTag(QueryTagSupport.java:159)
    org.apache.jsp.demo_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_005fquery_005f0(demo_jsp.java:163)
    org.apache.jsp.demo_jsp._jspService(demo_jsp.java:101)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: What's the complete stacktrace? Also, did you try with a forward-slash in the filename?

Comment: Derby Error: To me, this sounds like an issue of a project that was started in Sun/Oracle NetBeans and then transplanted to eclipse. Is this correct?

Comment: I did try a forward slash and did not work. the complete stcktrace is too long. Not sure how I can post it all here.

Comment: Yes you can, it will be reviewed. Otherwise post the exceptions and the causes.

Comment: Just added my original post with your request

Comment: You probably did not include the Derby jar files (derby.jar, derbyclient.jar) in the Deployment Assembly (project -> properties -> deployment assembly). Add those libraries there and re-create/deploy.